# datetime2 and ProviderManifestToken in Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-2, entity-framework-4

I have an MVC app using Entity Framework and a SQL Server 2008 database. I used the EF wizard to generate my data model.

I have a SQL Server table with a standard `DateTime` column. The EF model is using `System.DateTime`.

But when I try to insert a new record into this table from my application, without specifying a value for this DateTime column, I get the error:

> The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

I Googled a bit and found that people are editing the edmx and changing the `ProviderManifestToken`. Ovbiously that will be overwritten, so is there a more permanent fix or way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is because, like you said, you're not setting any value for that DateTime property on the entity which causes it to default to '0001-01-01' which is definitely out of range for ***[datetime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx)*** column on SQL Server. The datetime type date range is *January 1, 1753, through December 31, 9999*.

To solve this, you have to either assign an in range value to that property before sending it to SQL Server, or change your DB column type to [***datetime2***](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx) which has a date range of *0001-01-01 through 9999-12-31*.

Comment: If I don't explicitly set a value for an entity property, shouldn't EF insert a null?

Comment: No, it will be set to the default(DateTime) in .Net. Please note that DateTime is a *Value Type* and cannot be Null, however DateTime? can. There are number of ways in EF that you can auto populate this property (and basically any entity's property) based on its usage.